# how to show two keyboards simultaneously on one screen Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I require two keyboards one from the bottom and one from the up each of them for a different EditText which will get input simultaneously from two users .How to achieve this?

Comment: For Bottom One use default keyboard and for top one create your own dialog and present keyboard there

Comment: do u mean to say create your own keyboard on a dialog..i am really not sure if we can add extra buttons on a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure..

But one of the edittext must requires the Custom keyboard. If you want to use custom keyboard, the sample custom keyboard is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u6sylh64wpi7fd/Custom%20Keyboard.zip).

The orientation of custom keyboard you may required to be change as per your request.
More about custom keyboard `http://stackoverflow.com/a/11445934/2123594`

Comment: yeah there has to be one custom keyboard but the real issue which i will be facing is placing the custom keyboard in the opposite direction..do you any way to solve this?